# Javascript removeEventListener not working - event listener remains

Tags: javascript, events, event-listener

I've looked at a few ways around this, but I can't really tell, my code is:

```
lb = document.body;

if(lb.addEventListener){    
    lb.addEventListener('keyup',
    function(event){
        keyPress(event.keyCode)
    }, false);
}

//In another function.

if(document.body.removeEventListener){
    document.body.removeEventListener('keyup', function(event){event.keyCode}, false);
}
```

The remove  code is not working, haven't tried a great deal of solutions yet but its the last thing on my script and I just want it done.

Thank you all

Comment: you dont need the `false` argument

Comment: 2 problems: 1. you should remove the SAME function (reference it), not another one that looks the same; 2. the addEvenListener and removeEventlistener must be attached to the same object. I just discovered that 'document.addEventListener' cannot be removed with 'window.removeEventListener'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When calling removeEventListener, you have to give it the **same function instance** than to addEventListener:

```
var lb = document.body;

var callback = function(event){
    keyPress(event.keyCode)
};

if(lb.addEventListener){    
    lb.addEventListener('keyup', callback, false);
}

//In another function.

if(document.body.removeEventListener){
    document.body.removeEventListener('keyup', callback, false);
}
```

jQuery makes it easier to deal with this, thanks to its [namespaced events feature](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names):

```
$(lb).on('keyup.my_namespace', function () { ... })

// later

$(lb).off('keyup.my_namespace');
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant remove an anonymous function with removeEventListener, instead use the function name.
e.g:

```
if(lb.addEventListener){    
    lb.addEventListener('keyup', myFunction, false);
}

//In another function.

if(document.body.removeEventListener){
    document.body.removeEventListener('keyup', myFunction, false);
}
```

the new function:

```
function myFunction(e){
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *name* the handler function in order to reference it later when removing the listener:

```
lb.addEventListener('keyup', 
function keyup(event){ // assigns the handler to "keyup"
    keyPress(event.keyCode)
}, false);

document.body.removeEventListener('keyup', keyup, false);
```