# removeEventListener from body not working

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I'm trying to remove an event listener after a function has been called. But the event listener for "keyup" stays attached to the body, no matter what I try. What is wrong with the code?

```
function displayImage() {
  //this is a simplified version of the code
  var outerFrame = document.createElement('div');

  outerFrame.className = 'popup-outer';

  document.body.appendChild(outerFrame);

  document.body.addEventListener('keyup', hideImage.bind(outerFrame), false);
}

function hideImage(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    // this doesn't work, it stays attached to the body element
    document.body.removeEventListener('keyup', hideImage, false);
    document.body.removeChild(this);
  }

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript removeEventListener not working - event listener remains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651790/javascript-removeeventlistener-not-working-event-listener-remains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because technically

```
hideImage.bind(outerFrame)
```

is different from

```
hideImage
```

because the first one returns a copy of the function hideImage.

So when you try to unbind hideImage, the event manager does not find it because it registred a copy of it and thus nothing is removed :-/.

EDIT :

In your case, I guess you have no other choice but keeping track of your listeners. I went ahead and made this quickly, it should fix your problem.

```
    var listeners = {};

    function createDiv() {
      var outerFrame = document.createElement('div');
      outerFrame.className = 'popup-outer';
      return outerFrame;
    }

    function displayImage() {
      var div = createDiv();
      bindEvent(div);
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    }

    function bindEvent(el) {
        var handler = function(e) {
            hideImg.call(el, e);
        }
        listeners[el] = handler;
        document.body.addEventListener('keyup', handler, false);
    }

    function hideImg(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) { 
            // listeners[this] refers to the "private" handler variable we created in the bindEvent function
            document.body.removeEventListener('keyup', listeners[this], false);
            delete listeners[this];
            document.body.removeChild(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, I'm not fully understanding this, but it works and I'm happy with it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, indeed my code is not really commented as I made it quickly :-/, I might come back and add some little explanations tho :).